# Dúvida em relação à sintaxe de Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

Boa noite pessoal, minha dúvida é sobre um trecho de código que encontrei num livro sobre Python e OpenCV. O autor criou a função que vou colocar abaixo:

```
@property
def frame(self):
    if self._enteredFrame and self._frame is None:
        _, self._frame =  self._capture.retrieve()
    return self._frame
```

Minha dúvida é em relação à linha: _, self._frame =  self._capture.retrieve().
Porque tem um underline e uma vírgula antes de self._frame = ... ?

Comment: Hum, ainda não consegui entender a sintaxe lendo esse artigo. Mas obrigado pela resposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso é um desestruturador.
self._capture.retrieve() retorna uma tupla com 2 elementos, vamos supor 'maçã' e 'laranja'
Com a seguinte sintaxe:

```
frutas = ('maçã', 'laranja')
```

Você teria uma tupla com maçã na posição 0, e laranja na posição 1, mas você também pode pegar os valores dessa maneira:

```
fruta1, fruta2 = ('maçã', 'laranja')
```

Nesse caso fruta1 terá maçã, e fruta2 terá laranja.

Se você não quiser utilizar o primeiro valor retornado, é recomendável que você utilize um _ para capturar esse valor, como é o caso do seu código, ou seja, _ contém o primeiro valor da tupla, que é irrelevante, e self._frame contém o segundo valor da tupla.

Comment: Ah ta, entendi, muito obrigado!!